# Finding core javascript calls that are incompatible with IE6/7/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Hey is there a jslint-like inspector that will flag on calls that are incompatible with older versions of IE? or just cross browser incompatible calls in general?

Comment: +1 That would be something valuable to have.

Comment: Any examples for incompatible calls that JSLint doesn't detect?

Comment: Array.isArray([]); IE8 doesnt have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) with a custom [externs file](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#externs) which doesn't define any of the things missing in IE from the compatibility table of your choice (the kangax one linked above, or you could use one from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross browser library like [MooTools](http://mootools.net/). It automatically adds missing methods for IE, also makes writing javascript easier.

Comment: I use cross browser libraries, I just accidently do stuff like Array.isArray().

Comment: which cross-browser library are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The WTP project for eclipse allows you to select different browser support javascript packages for JS projects.  It certainly supplies completion only for the items actually in the different browsers, but I'm not sure if it flags other usage as errors.